# Duplicate Community Bulletin election entries

Tags: support, election, community-bulletin

Browsing the meta site, I came across this little oddity:

[image]

As you can see, there are two election entries. Wouldn't it be better to just have a single link for the entire election, as the nominations are readily visible from there?

Or, even better, use something like:

> event  2013 Community Moderator Election - nominations end in 6 days, election ends Feb 19

?

Comment: One of the mods created this, apparently forgetting that the system automatically creates one. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLoLX.gif]

Comment: Wait, it was removed, or is it not reproducible?

Comment: It was removed.

Comment: This should probably be tagged [meta-tag:status-completed].